# main domain in cpanel different from actual website domain

Tags: cpanel

When i log in to CPanel the main domain it shows on the first page and even when creating email accounts is different from the actual website domain.

The domain cpanel is showing is actually an older domain i created earlier but due to a mistake in the name, I registered another domain and moved all the content of the older site to the newer one. The newer site works perfectly but the issue i face now is that within cpanel i'm not able to do some things like create emails because it is showing a different domain name.

[image: domain in cpanel]

Actual domain is **hanjakprofessionals.com**

My web host claims he never did anything other than create for me a new domain account.
i assume that the problem could be in the way i migrated from the older site, however, i can't undo because I've made many changes in the newer site.
I noticed that some folders in cpanel like in mail folder and etc, their name is the older domain name which i edited to the newer but still no difference.
Is there anywhere i can change within cpanel to enable it reflect the current domain name? I welcome all ideas. thanks

Answer (score 0):

on further checking i found that the cpanel user account i was using was of the older domain account so cpanel was actually loading the older account. I now logged in using the user account for that particular domain and it shows the actual domain in cpanel.
This is now resolved however i notice that cpanel allows one to login to another domain account yet the domain/url that was accessed was a different one.